# Initialization of a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, matrix

Is there a way to initialize a vector of vectors in the same ,quick, manner as you initialize a matrix?

```
typedef int type;

type matrix[2][2]=
{
{1,0},{0,1}
};

vector<vector<type> > vectorMatrix;  //???
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the single vector you can use following:

```
typedef int type;
type elements[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
vector<int> vec(elements, elements + sizeof(elements) / sizeof(type) );
```

Based on that you could use following:

```
type matrix[2][2]=
{
   {1,0},{0,1}
};

vector<int> row_0_vec(matrix[0], matrix[0] + sizeof(matrix[0]) / sizeof(type) );

vector<int> row_1_vec(matrix[1], matrix[1] + sizeof(matrix[1]) / sizeof(type) );

vector<vector<type> > vectorMatrix;
vectorMatrix.push_back(row_0_vec);
vectorMatrix.push_back(row_1_vec);
```

In [c++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists), you be able to initialize standard containers in a same way as arrays.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vector_of_vectors;
```

then if you want to add, you can use this procedure:

```
vector_of_vectors.resize(#rows); //just changed the number of rows in the vector
vector_of_vectors[row#].push_back(someInt); //this adds a column
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> myRow;
myRow.push_back(someInt);
vector_of_vectors.push_back(myRow);
```

So, in your case, you should be able to say:

```
vector_of_vectors.resize(2);
vector_of_vectors[0].resize(2);
vector_of_vectors[1].resize(2);
for(int i=0; i < 2; i++)
 for(int j=0; j < 2; j++)
   vector_of_vectors[i][j] = yourInt;
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++0x, I think you can use the same syntax as for your `matrix`.

In C++03, you have to write some tedious code to populate it. Boost.Assign might be able to simplify it somewhat, using something like the following untested code:

```
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>

vector<vector<type> > v;
v += list_of(1)(0), list_of(0)(1);
```

or even

```
vector<vector<type> > v = list_of(list_of(1)(0))(list_of(0)(1));
```

Comment: I tried that but it does not seem to work. I have a `vector<vector<int>` and I would like to initialize the first element of the variable to one so that I have a vector of just one element vector initialized to one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @tuxworker: In C++11, that's `vector<vector<int>> v {{1}};`. With Boost.Assign in C++03, something like `vector<vector<int> > v = list_of(list_of(1));`. If that doesn't work, ask a new question showing what you're trying and describing what goes wrong.

Comment: Indeed I tried `vector<vector<int> > v(10); v+= list_of(list_of(1));` and `vector<vector<int> > v(10); v = list_of(list_of(1));` and I've got a compilation error. I think it would be also better using in addition repeat but I don't know how. I will ask a new question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the matrix is completely filled -

```
vector< vector<int> > TwoDVec(ROWS, vector<int>(COLS));
//Returns a matrix of dimensions ROWS*COLS with all elements as 0
//Initialize as -
TwoDVec[0][0] = 0;
TwoDVec[0][1] = 1;
..
.
```

Update : I found there's a better way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21758334/2008838)

else if there are variable number of elements in each row(not a matrix) -

```
vector< vector<int> > TwoDVec(ROWS);
for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++){
    while(there_are_elements_in_row[i]){           //pseudocode
        TwoDVec[i].push_back(element);
    }
}
```