# Creating a dynamic 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I need to have a 2D array of double.
Its width is around 900. Its height as well (the same width value).

Dealing with two loops (one for the width and one for the height), I really need to get access to all the pixels of the 900X900 image that I will process.

The size of the array is too big (error when specifying the number of raw and column).

I thought about establishing that with a dynamic array to optimize the time of calculation and to free the memory everytime I deal with one pixel on the two loops.

But I really cannot find the syntax I would like to have to declare a 2D dynamic array (malloc, setting array element values and freeing the memory).

Comment: Hint: in C++, `std::vector` is new `malloc`.

Comment: 900х900х4=3.2M It's not no much... dynamic arrays are very slow. Give us more info about how you get this image and how you process it. What error do you have?

Comment: it's written stack over flow !

Comment: when it's about to process a window of the image (100X100 for instance), I have great calculations for it, but I want to process the whole image, thus, when I change the number of elements of my array to 900 :: ALERT with Stack over flow.

Comment: Do not create it on stack. Use malloc to allocate memory for array or increase stack size in your compiler options.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a class:

```
class Matrix2D {
    typedef std::vector<double> Column;
    std::vector<Column> columns;
public:
    Matrix2D(unsigned int width, unsigned int height) :
    columns(width, Column(height)) {
    }

    double& at(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) {
        return columns[i][j];
    }
};

Matrix2D matrix(900, 900);

matrix.at(45, 65) = 1234.5678;
```

Comment: Waaw! The result is showed up in few seconds!!!!!!
I was waiting 1- 2 minutes to deal with one small window (300X300) of the whole image 

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> *I need to have a 2D array of `double`*

Since you are using C++ you should use STL classes that will take care of ugly memory management for you. So you are actually looking for `std::vector< std::vector<double> >`, or for the sake of the readability of your code:

```
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<double> DVector;      // row represented by vector of doubles
typedef std::vector<DVector> MyVector;    // 2D array as a vector of these rows
```

And then avoid using dynamic allocation wherever it's possible to do so. Take advantage of [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization):

```
{
    MyVectorarr;  // vector object with automatic storage duration
} // <-- vector is automatically destructed when execution goes out of scope
```

Questions that might help you:
[Multi-dimensional vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/823562/1168156)
[Initialization of a vector of vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3061247/1168156)
[vector of vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3438377/1168156)

Comment: Thank you for that. But here, in the code example that  you have showed, how to set the values of the created vector?

Comment: @ZeusM: Check my edit, I added links to questions that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I associate malloc with pure C, not C++ (as the prior answer points yout, you should use std::vector).  However, if you really want to:

```
// allocate the memory in a block
double* block = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * xSize * ySize);
// allocate memory for the accessor array
double* accessor = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double*) * xSize);
// assign memory addresses
double* curPtr = block;
for (int i = 0; i < xSize; ++i) {
    accessor[i] = curPtr;
    curPtr += ySize;
}

// you can now access the array via accessor[x][y]

// now need to free malloced memory:
free(accessor);
free(block);
```

If you do it this way, I highly suggest tying it to the RAII pattern, otherwise you'll eventually get a memory leak.  Using the STL's containers is a better approach.