# How to initialize 2d vector using constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

I know how to initialize 1d vector like this

```
int myints[] = {16,2,77,29};
std::vector<int> fifth(myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int));
```

suppose I have 2d data.

```
float yy[][2] = {{20.0, 20.0}, {80.0, 80.0}, {20.0, 80.0}, {80.0, 20.0}};
```

How can I initialize a 2d vector ?

Comment: Keep in mind that vectors are contiguous in memory

Comment: @Jarod42 You should not edit OP's code in the question.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: `float yy = {{..}}` was invalid. And my edit doesn't invalidate posted answers.

Comment: @Jarod42: That it was invalid was part of the question, I think.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: may I revert back to previous code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ 11 you can initialize a vector of vectors like this:

```
auto yy = std::vector<std::vector<float>>
{
    {20.0, 20.0},
    {80.0, 80.0},
    {20.0, 80.0},
    {80.0, 20.0}
};
```

Comment: Things to look into for more information include initializer_lists and uniform initialization in c++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza That works just as well in this case. My personal preference is for 'Almost Always Auto'. In this situation it makes little difference since we're committed to the type std::vector<std::vector<float>>, and we're not saving on any typing. Here it is simply a matter of style. Ideally, it serves to inform the programmer not to think of yy as a vector of vectors, but rather to think of it as any 2D container, though a better name for yy may be desired to drive that point home.

Comment: That really makes no sense at all. Because the thing on the RHS is explicitly a vector of vectors. Also, this requires that the copy constructor be accessible. In this case it works, but it doesn't always. It is an extra restriction for little gain.

Comment: It does not require that a copy constructor be accessible, it requires that either a copy constructor or a move constructor be accessible, and yes that is a restriction, but in this case that restriction is also imposed by using std::vector which requires that objects be copyable or movable, so there is no real difference other than style in this case.

Answer (score 6):

In current C++ (since 2011) you can initialize such vector in constructor:

```
vector<vector<float>> yy
{
    {20.0, 20.0},
    {80.0, 80.0},
    {20.0, 80.0},
    {80.0, 20.0}
};
```

See it alive: http://ideone.com/GJQ5IU.

Comment: @sefat: you need C++11 (`-std=c++11` in gcc compiler flag).

Comment: @Jarod42: thank u . i have configured codeblocks for c++11 and now it works .

Answer (score 4):

In case you do not know the values beforehand still you can initialize a 2D vector with an initial value.

```
vector< vector <int> > arr(10, vector <int> (10, 0));
```

The above code will initialize a 2D vector of 10X10 with all index value as zero(0).